# CSS: Safari Mobile doesn't support background-position offset

Tags: css, mobile-safari, background-image, background-position

I have this property with multiple background images and their respective positions:

```
#my_div {
    background-image:url("..."), url("..."), url("...");
    background-position:right bottom, right bottom, right 15px top 17px;
}
```

The positioning for the third image works fine on FF, IE10, Chrome.. but unfortunately not on Safari Mobile. It renders the right and top thing but not the offsets (15px for right and 17px for top).. I couldn't find any reference on this. How would you deal with this? I'd avoid having to modify the image manually adding transparent borders to make the offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mobile Safari (as well as the Android browser) doesn't support the four-value syntax yet. (see the [MDN article on background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position#Browser_compatibility)).

One possible workaround would be to extract the background image which should have the offset and put it in a pseudo element that has the corresponding offsets.

```
#my_div:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;

  height: 50px; /* Height of your image / parent div */
  width: 50px; /* Width of your image / parent div */

  /* Your offset */
  top: 17px; 
  right: 15px;

  background-image: url("...");
  background-position: right top;
}
```

For easier understanding I created a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pKWvp/1/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) . You know if they're planning to support this on Mobile Safari (and Android browser)?

Comment: I don't know anything for sure but the WebKit Nightlies (= alpha versions of the rendering engine behind Safari and Mobile Safari) already support the four-value syntax. So it can be expected to come within one of the next versions. Don't know anything about Android though.

Comment: I like this solution, but it doesn't work if you want to vertically center the background image, and the height of the element is dynamic

Comment: for elements that have fluid dimensions, in the case where you want to specify a right space or a bottom space, and have the other dimension centered, the best cross-browser/platform way is to add an empty transparent space to the image itself and do something like 

background-position: right center;
or 
background-position: center bottom

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using the css calc function: http://briantree.se/quick-tip-02-use-css-calc-properly-position-background-images/

It's might be easier/cleaner than using pseudo elements.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought your question was regarding the issue with the background positioning. The right 15px and top 17px offsets.

Comment: Oh my god. My fault. I switched questions... -.- I thought your replied to another question I opened. Sorry :D